# Random permalinks in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a code to retrieve random wp posts,It works perfectly the problem is it shows recently added media and its permalink.What changes to be made in the following code to retrieve random permalinks instead of recently added.

```
<?

function get_match( $regex, $content ) {
    preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
} 


$shortcode_args = shortcode_parse_atts(get_match('/\[gallery\s(.*)\]/isU', $post->post_content));


$ids = $shortcode_args["ids"];


$attachments = get_posts(
    array(
        'include' => $ids, 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'order' => 'menu_order ID', 
        'orderby' => 'post__in', 
    )
);



foreach ($attachments as &$pos) {



$perm = get_permalink($pos->ID);
$img =  wp_get_attachment_link( $pos->ID, 'thumbnail',true  ); 

 echo('<a href="'.$perm.'">'.$img.'</a>');


}
?>
```

Comment: `It works perfectly the problem is...` This statement makes about as much sense as the rest of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
'post_type' => 'attachment', //retrives all attachements so change that to

'post_type' => 'post',// or your custom_post_type if you want to get only your custom post type
```

and also remove

```
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
```